# Authenticate Username and Password in OpenStack with pkgcloud

Tags: node.js, openstack, pkgcloud

I'm trying to call an API for password authentication in OpenStack. This is API that I curl and get the access token: 
[Password authentication with unscoped authorization](https://docs.openstack.org/api-ref/identity/v3/?expanded=password-authentication-with-unscoped-authorization-detail,password-authentication-with-scoped-authorization-detail#password-authentication-with-unscoped-authorization)

I want to do the same thing in NodeJS and I'm a little confused. Can I do it cause I'm thinking maybe the problem is that it is not possible to do it like this; however this is the code that I've been trying:

```
var pkgcloud = require('pkgcloud');

var client = pkgcloud.compute.createClient({
    provider: 'openstack',
    username: <username>,
    password: <password>,
    authUrl: 'http://<ip>:<port>/',
    basePath: 'v3'
});
  client.getFlavors(function (err, flavors) {
    console.log("Error", err)
    console.log("Flavors", flavors)
})

client.getServers(function (err, servers) {
    console.log("Error", err)
    console.log("Servers", servers)
})
```

The getFlavors and getServers functions return 405 Method Not Allowed - The method is not allowed for the requested URL.

what is wrong with my code? and if I have to use another URL for getFlavors or any other function, where should I put it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did what Iarsks has said and also added a tenant id and it worked fine.

This is the config that I used:

```
var config = {
    provider: 'openstack',
    keystoneAuthVersion: 'v3',
    authUrl: '...',
    domainId: 'default',
    username: <username>,
    password: <password>,
    region: <region name which is provided in the cloud.yaml file in OpenStack>,
    tenantId: <the same as the Project ID>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, rather than specifying `basePath: 'v3'`, you should explicitly be setting the Keystone version via `keystoneAUthVersion`. Simply setting `basePath` like that will ultimately result in bad requests.

When using v3 authentication, you need to provide a `domainId` (or `domainName`) as part of your request.

Lastly, you may need to ensure you are providing a valid `region`.

The following works correctly against my OpenStack environment:

```
var pkgcloud = require('pkgcloud');

var client = pkgcloud.compute.createClient({
    provider: 'openstack',
    keystoneAuthVersion: 'v3',
    authUrl: '...',
    domainId: 'default',
    username: 'lars',
    password: '...',
    region: 'my-region'
})

client.getFlavors(function (err, flavors) {
    console.log("Error", err)
    console.log("Flavors", flavors)
})
```

Comment: thanks! but I keep getting an error: "Cannot read property of 'id' of undefined" and I searched but nothing related came up. Do you know what it is for?

Comment: I don't. It sounds like something is unexpectedly returning an undefined value, which can sometimes suggest a bug or unexpected response from the server, but I don't know enough javascript to suggest where to start debugging.  The above works for me with `pkgcloud` version `2.2.0`.